# Using dynamic arrays and offset based on certain criteria

Tags: excel

Currently, I am trying to obtain values from a different excel workbook (workbook b) for use in my current excel workbook (workbook a).

Here are the workbooks in question:

***Workbook a:*** 
[image]

***Workbook b:***
[image]

I'm trying to automatically fill in 'Output' by using index match with Output and the Unique ID which is present in both workbooks. However, a 0 will be returned  where there is no value in the numbering field. I want excel to search in this way (https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNDFL.png), where the search would start from the Unique ID number leftwards 2 columns and continue upwards until it finds a value. However, I've tried some combinations of offset and IF, but I haven't succeeded yet. I would be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

*I should add that I am very new to excel and have only really learned what I know now through web searches.

Comment: Did you try VLOOKUP?

Comment: I was under the impression that I needed an Offset to accomplish this and VLOOKUP was inferior in that aspect, and that Index match could accomplish everything else that VLOOKUP could.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your problem, your impression is _wrong_ and you should try VLOOKUP.

Comment: Looks like I was hasty in determining VLOOKUP to be inferior. Thanks for the tip, I'll look more deeply into VLOOPUP for future solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=LOOKUP(9.9E+307,OFFSET([Book2]Sheet3!$A$6,0,0,MATCH(A2,[Book2]Sheet3!$C$6:$C$15,0)))
```

Change the Book and Sheet as appropriate.

In this formula:

- `MATCH` returns the row of the matching `Unique ID` and is used as the `Height` argument for the `OFFSET` function.
- `OFFSET` then creates an array of `MATCH` Rows.

  - Due to how your table is set up, this will either match a blank in Column A, or the first matching entry for the `ID`
- `LOOKUP`, where the lookup_value is higher than anything found in `lookup_array` will return the last actual value in the array.

  - IF your Output's were text, the formula would need to be altered a bit.

[image]

**Book2 Sheet3:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed write-up, some of the elements in the code is still new to me, but nothing I cannot search up on my own. Once again, thank you for the excellent write-up!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula

```
=INDEX('C:\Users\HARUN\Documents\[b.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$6:$B$15,MATCH(A2,'C:\Users\HARUN\Documents\[b.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C$6:$C$15,0),1)
```

Change the file location and sheet name in case of you.

Comment: I've tried this code and it seems to encounter the same problem as my previous attempted solutions in that it returns a 0 when the is no value in the numbering column next to the Unique ID.